# GCP .NET Core Application can't connect to SQL Server but local application can

Tags: sql-server, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When running my application through Visual Studio IIS Express, I connect perfectly fine to the GCP-hosted SQL Server instance I am running.

However, when publishing to GCP, the page ends up as a 500 error. Digging through the mountain of logs that GCP gave me, I managed to find this entry which I believe is the source of the issue. What can I do to diagnose this issue? I am a GCP amateur and I don't know where to start.

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

Comment: Do you use a Cloud SQL service or a custom VM? Can you share more about your database configuration (and network configuration)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The database is a SQL Server 2019 Standard CU13 instance hosted on us-central1-a. I can also access it through SSMS perfectly fine. I don't know where to get the information for the network configuration - like I said, I'm an amateur. I can provide any info if you can point me where to find it!

Comment: I configured the SQL instance to allow all IPs and that got it working. My next step is to figure out what the IP of the App Engine instance is.

Comment: App Engine haven't configuration public or private IP and so you can't filter on only one IP. However, I think you can restrict access from only private IP ranges if you plug a serverless VPC connector on App Engine https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/connecting-vpc

Comment: You have mentioned `I configured the SQL instance to allow all IPs and that got it working` hence post your resolution as answer for the question so that the community will know how to solve it if someone comes across the same issue. For `My next step is to figure out what the IP of the App Engine instance is` you can create a new stack overflow question.